# Oozie Hive version

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am using AWS, Hive version 1.0. I used row_number() in one of my queries. This query is working fine in Hue and CLI. But when I added the same query in `oozie Hive action`, my workflow failed with below error message.

```
 5011 [main] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver  - FAILED: ParseException line 3:217 mismatched input '(' expecting FROM near 'over' in from clause

  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 3:217 mismatched input '(' expecting FROM near 'over' in from clause
```

I tried to investigate the root cause of error and found, **`oozie using Hive version 0.10`** and Hive 0.10 does not support row_number(). Here are a few JAR's I took from log which oozie is using to execute Hive queries:

```
File: hive-shims-0.10.0.jar
File: hive-service-0.10.0.jar
File: hive-pdk-0.10.0.jar
File: hive-serde-0.10.0.jar
```

Why is there a version difference and how we can redirect the oozie to correct hive version?

I have read **`POM.XML`** keep the version of ecosystems but were not able to find its location.

Comment: So it appears to be an **AWS** issue, if they package obsolete ShareLibs with Oozie.

Comment: Seems to be and found AWS inconsistent